# Lua scripting for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, lua

I am working on a game project with SceneKit for iOS platform and want to use Lua scripting to load resources (3D files, Music) using commands from Lua script, so that the designer will write commands in Lua to load his files on a specific point on the scene and also adjust its properties and interaction with other nodes etc.And a code will be written to execute the command. I understand that I have to include the Lua API and write a bridge file to integrate the API, but not sure how to achieve the thing i mentioned. can someone suggest any examples of this type or any ideas are apreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [lua4swift](https://github.com/sdegutis/lua4swift) project in GitHub - it has a project with Swift bindings to Lua

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at doing this in the past. I was building Lua from source.

1. To do that, you'll need create a bridging header. If you make a new `C` header file, Xcode should ask you if you want to make a bridging header. 
   Just as an FYI, when it makes this file, it also sets the swift compiler flag "Objective-C Bridging Header" to point to the right file.

   2. Then you need to copy the Lua source code into the project and get it to build. At this point, you haven't yet exposed the Lua code to swift.
   3. Include the appropriate Lua header files into the bridging header. So put something like this into it: `#include "lua.h"`

At this point, you will want to write some functions to bridge some of the Lua macros which they use. These aren't compatible with swift, so you will need to rewrite them.

For a reference, check out the developer's guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-ID122).